# Windows 8 crashed after ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

Windows 8:
I had windows 8 on my laptop - lenovo G500 essential, 1TB hard disk. I shrinked C drive and obtained 435GB as unallocated space.

BIOS:
I `disabled secure boot` and `enabled uefi`.

Installing Ubuntu:
I installed Ubuntu 12.04 from DVD. It was working fine. I did shutdown Ubuntu. When I started again I saw Ubuntu, Windows etc. I was able to boot Ubuntu without any trouble. But when I tried to boot Windows I got a "Disk error". I pressed enter which took me back to the OS menu. I clicked on System setup which took me to BIOS screen. Whenever I change the Boot order and give priority to Windows or Ubuntu in BIOS, the corresponding OS worked.

Then I wanted to fix this, so I tried to do `Ubuntu boot repair`. I go got prompts like, `"Win efi detected. Do you want to actiavate(Take backup and rename windows efi files). Do you want to continue(Yes/No)"` for which I selected `"Yes"`. I got message like boot repair was successful.

From my next restart, I only get grub screen. If I type exit, I get boot menu option. When I select Ubuntu, It works fine. But if I select Windows, I get a `"disk error"`

How should I fix this?

Comment: Please post the URL that Boot Repair presented you. If you don't have that URL, instead run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/), post the `RESULTS.txt` file that it produces to a [pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/), and and post the URL to your document here. Briefly, I suspect you've got a mixed-mode EFI/BIOS installation, but the details from Boot Repair/Boot Info Script are necessary for a complete diagnosis.

Comment: @RodSmith I pasted the contents of Results.txt here http://paste.ubuntu.com/6987393/

Answer (score 0):

Your Boot Repair output shows no evidence of the Microsoft boot loader files on your disk; however, there are other hints that they may actually still be there. In any event, I recommend you do the following:

1. In Linux, back up the entire `/boot/efi` directory tree. A file-level backup (using `cp`, `tar`, or the like) should be adequate.
2. Re-run Boot Repair. Enter the Advanced menu and tell it to restore the backups it made.
3. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and create a boot medium with it.
4. Test rEFInd. You should be able to boot both Windows and Ubuntu.
5. If rEFInd can boot both OSes, install the Debian-package version in Ubuntu.

With any luck, this will get you booting both OSes via rEFInd from the hard disk, bypassing GRUB. If you have further problems, post back with details.